# Reload web source code without refreshing the page with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dom, reload

Hello I would like to ask if there is any way to refresh source code of site without refreshing page. The problem is when I load page http://107.170.101.241:8080/getTableColumn/ and put there some information - you can see in my code below and then click Analyse there is displayed new textarea. I want to get text from this textarea but I cant because source code is “old” and xpath cant find it. Last line of code is what I want to print to console. I tried time.sleep etc. and nothing helped.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("http://107.170.101.241:8080/getTableColumn/")
time.sleep(1)

datab = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='dbVendor']")
database = Select(datab)
database.select_by_visible_text("Sybase")

datab2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='options']")
database2 = Select(datab2)
database2.select_by_visible_text("Show By SQL Clause")

txt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='sql']")
txt.clear()
txt.send_keys("select trd.M_NB as 'Trade_number' from CRD_TRADE_REP trd")

txt1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='metadata']")
txt1.clear()
txt1.send_keys("CRD_TRADE_REP, M_NB")

analyze = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
analyze.send_keys("")
analyze.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#cant find this textarea below
out = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='outputText']")
```

Here is Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/martinkubicka/Documents/fiverrgde.py", line 32, in <module>
    out = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='outputText']")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[@name='outputText']"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
```

Comment: Update the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: i think you just have a sync issue...  you are pressing your button and expecting the output to be "instantly" present... but, i assume, there are scripts that need to run first.... Are you looking for output text before it's present?  - Add an implict wait when you create your driver OR add a explicit wait to wait for it to be present - see here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Your output text is in an iframe

Comment: @RichEdwards when I print iframe as text it give me nothing. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In devtools, If you scroll up from your element, you can see your output textarea is nested in:

```
<iframe name="result" id="result" style="height: 180px; width: 800px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
```

These need extra handling in selenium.

Try this at the end of your script:

```
#Get the frame
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='result']")))

#wait for your object to be ready - i  use clickable as i like it
out = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//textarea[@name='outputText']")))

print(out.text)
#do stuff your stuff to the "out" element here

#when ready to go back to the main page content (not the iframe)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

When i run your code with that addition i get the output:

> Tables: tetSelect CRD_TRADE_REP(1,40) Columns: selectList
> CRD_TRADE_REP.M_NB(1,12)